# How to fill an array with swf object values using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, each

To start here is the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5s0cgvvw/1/

I'm looking to get the value (associated to FlashVars name) of each object present inside a container :

HTML :

```
<object width="160" height="750" data="banner_160x750.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="banner_160x750.swf"> 
    <param name="quality" value="best"> 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
    <param name="scale" value="default"> 
    <param name="FlashVars" value="0x0"> <!-- Target value -->
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"> 
</object>

<object width="970" height="250" data="Panel1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="Panel1.swf"> 
    <param name="quality" value="best"> 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
    <param name="scale" value="default"> 
    <param name="FlashVars" value="160x0"> <!-- Target value -->
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"> 
</object>

<object width="160" height="750" data="banner_160x750.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="banner_160x750.swf"> 
    <param name="quality" value="best"> 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
    <param name="scale" value="default"> 
    <param name="FlashVars" value="1130x0"> <!-- Target value -->
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"> 
</object>

<object width="300" height="250" data="Banner1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="Banner1.swf"> 
    <param name="quality" value="best"> 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
    <param name="scale" value="default"> 
    <param name="FlashVars" value="400x400"> <!-- Target value -->
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"> 
</object>
```

Actual Jquery code:

```
var myArray = []; // create an empty array
$('div object').each(function() {
    var pickValue = $( "param[name='FlashVars']").attr('value');
    myArray.push(pickValue);
});

alert(myArray);
```

... and I'd like to put those information in an array to treat them later (for positioning).

With my actual code, the array shows 4 results (which is good because I've got 4 flash objects) but they are all the same (0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0). I don't get why the result is 0x0 as it's the first flash value. Looks like it's not going inside the other objects.

My goal is to fill myArray like this : [0x0,160x0,1130x0,400x400].

Thanks!

Damien

---

### **UPDATE**

The Correct answer is this. (Thanks again J08691)

```
var myArray = [];
$('object').each(function() {
    var pickValue = $(this).find('param[name="FlashVars"]').attr('value');
    myArray.push(pickValue);
});
alert(myArray);
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. Not part of it here and the rest on jsFiddle. Also, in your fiddle you have `myArray` and `aArray`. Which one is the array? And where in the fiddle is an element with the class `entry-content`? Finally, what you really want for your selector is `$(this).find('param[name="FlashVars"]').attr('value');` http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5s0cgvvw/2/

Comment: Hi j08691, Thanks for your help! Next time I will copy the whole code. I thought it was better to simplify it here and put the link. 
myArray and aArray should be the same, my bad... and the class entry-content should not be here either. I did not clean my code correctly.